# How can I collapse Jackson encoding of a class to be encoding of one instance variable?

Tags: java, json, encoding, jackson

I have a set of classes where one class has an instance variable of another class.

```
public class Outer {
    public Inner inner;
}
public class Inner {
    public HashMap data;
}
```

I'm using Jackson to encode this data structure into JSON, and by default, get the following encoding:

```
{ inner: { data: { a : 1, b: 2 } } } // a:1,b:2 is contents of data HashMap
```

What I need to do<sup>[1]</sup> is to skip the `"data"` layer in JSON maps - essentially, replacing the encoding of Inner class with encoding of one of its instance variables (HashMap data):

```
{ inner: { a : 1, b: 2 } }
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

I'm assuming that would involve custom Jackson encoder for Inner class but unsure if that's the easiest and best approach and if so, how to write it effectively.

NOTES:

- Just to be clear, Inner class is guaranteed to only have one encodable member (`data`). There are other public members but they have `@JsonIgnore` annotation to avoid encoding them.
- The solution should not involve writing hand-built encoding code for HashMap itself. I only used HashMap for simplicity of the example; in reality `data` is of a complex class for which hand-written encoder is NOT feasible nor desirable.
- Only JSON encoding matters. No need for matching decoder.
- [1] To avoid X-Y problem types of answers/comments, the requirement is to do just, exactly, what I outlined. I cannot change the code that reads the JSON on the other end and ignores the `data` layer. I cannot change the class structure.

Comment: If, in reality, data is of a complex class and not a map, then JsonUnwrapped should work. You shouldn't say it's a map, if it is not a map.

Comment: @JBNizet - that seems like a good answer!